# background-blend-mode not working on Safari CSS

Tags: css, safari, webkit, css-animations, background-blend-mode

I am developing a product. I made a flash of lightning. This animation works great on chrome. But there is no animation on Safari. Is this problem caused by background-blend-mode or another thing?

Code:

```
.block-2 {
    -webkit-animation-name: thund;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    background-blend-mode: normal;
    background-image:url(thunder.png), url(red-bg.jpg);
    background-position: 99%, 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

@keyframes thund {
  0% {   background-blend-mode: normal;
    }
  100% {   background-blend-mode: hue;
    }
  }

@-webkit-keyframes thund {
0% {   background-blend-mode: normal;
  ;}
100% {   background-blend-mode: hue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to create this as a snippet and upload your images?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may be because of your safari version. Support for `background-blend-mode` in safari starts from version 10.1, you can find this in caniuse.com. Another problem might be the animation of `background-blend-mode`, according to W3 schools `background-blend-mode` is not animatable.You can find this in this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-blend-mode.asp) but I am not completely sure about this(background-blend-mode not being animatable).This is because I tried it and it worked. So the problem might be the Safari version.