# Background-blend-mode set to screen does not work on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, background, background-blend-mode

So I'm new to coding and found out recently that you can apply linear-gradient to text. I did it using background linear gradient and the background-blend-mode like so:

```
#header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: .5rem;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #886434; /* FALLBACK COLOR */
    background: linear-gradient(limegreen, transparent), linear-gradient(90deg, skyblue, transparent), linear-gradient(-90deg, coral, transparent);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

and it looks really cool on desktop, but when I deployed the web page via GitHub pages and opened it on my phone in Safari the background-blend-mode is not working. I also tried using Chrome for iOS, but got the same result.

[Here](https://zumbeto.github.io/club-website-project/) is the link to Github pages and here is the [link](https://github.com/zumbeto/club-website-project) to the entire repository.

I would really appreciate it if someone enlightens me on the subject as I couldn't find anything online that explains it, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [background-blend-mode not working on Safari CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388390/background-blend-mode-not-working-on-safari-css)

Comment: I do not think that the problem could be the Safari version as I am using the latest one and tried it on Chrome with the same result. Also I am not trying to animate the blend-mode, so unfortunately this does not answer my question.

Comment: This is an iOS specific issue. Browsers on iOS are only allowed to use the same rendering engine (Webkit) as Safari, so on iPhone the issue will be the same regardless of what browser you use. The Github page displays perfectly on my Android browsers that do not use Webkit. From the number of SO questions on it, it seems that Safari has issues with consistently rendering `background-blend-mode`.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I checked it on an Android device and it displays how it should. I thought there was something wrong with my code.